# Specify what folder to use for creating class object Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, oop

I've got a small problem (maybe it isnt even a problem)

I am making an application in Ruby, and the folder/file structure goes something like this:

```
OrderSet/
..item.rb
..file.rb
..order_object.rb
OrderGet/
..item.rb
..files.rb
..order.rb
```

As you can see I got two item.rb files, they are both different in class structure. Now I need to create an OrderSet/item.rb object, how do I specify it needs to look in OrderSet and does not get the OrderGet one?

I have to make clear, all files are required in the main rb file.

I have tried doing OrderSet.Item (the class is called Item inside the item.rb) but it complains about an ininitialized constant OrderSet

Thanks in advance!

[edit]
I have also tried to make modules out of it, maybe I don't understand the concept correctly, but I have tried it with OrderSet.Item.new (OrderSet as module name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a module to create a namespace - that way each set of classes would be encapsulated to what they do (the folder name from your example). So classes in OrderSet would be wrapped in a module for example OrderSet/item.rb would become:

```
module OrderSet
  class Item
    # methods and properties
  end
end
```

Then you could use it like

```
new_order_set = OrderSet::Item.new
```

RubyMonk has a lesson called [Modules As Namespaces](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/35-modules/lessons/80-modules-as-namespaces) which has more details and examples you can run in your browser.